# Constructor with an ifstream

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, ifstream

I want to put a constructor that can read data from a file but something is wrong, my code is briefly :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A { 
A(vector<string> words)
  :words(words)
    {}
A(ifstream& myfile)
 { string line;
     if (myfile.is_open()) {
          cout << "Hello world !" << endl;
          while ( getline (myfile,line) )
                { words.push_back(line);
                  }
           myfile.close();
      } 
  }

private:
vector<string> words;
};

int main() {

ifstream file("test.txt")
A test(file);

}
```

The second constructor does not print "Hello world !", it means `myfile.is_open()` is `false` in the constructor. There is no problem with file itself. How to fix this ?
(Before, the constructor was not a reference and I got the error `call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of ‘std::ifstream’ (aka ‘basic_ifstream’)`)

Comment: Is `test.txt` in the current working directory when the program is run?  Because that's what your code is assuming.

Comment: You might add some error checking in `main`. Pretty sure the file isn't open there either. The file is probably not in your working directory. One easy way to find where that is would be to create a file there and then look for it.

Comment: I know this may be your code, but you could have minimized this code by simply testing immediately in `main` to see if the file is opened, without introducing `A` at all.

Comment: Alright I'll check that in a few seconds. After reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786758/initializing-an-ifstream-variable-in-constructor-of-class , I think that what I did might not be possible.

Comment: In fact you're right, I modified the main to print the file's data but it does not print anything. It works with another program with another main in the same working directory but it doesn't work with this main...

Comment: Should the makefile include something special for ifstreams ?

Comment: The main now works but the error is still the same...

Comment: The question you linked is about something different than what you're doing. If the file is opened properly in `main` then the code in your constructor, or any other function that takes a reference to a stream, should work fine.

Comment: After adding an include for <iostream>, making the constructor public and adding a semicolon after file("test.txt") this compiles and runs in online GDB.